# How I can delete the children of folder using CoreData?

Tags: swift, core-data, delete-file

```
func deleteFolder(indexSet : IndexSet) {
    for folder in indexSet {
        let folderToDelete = folders[folder]
        
        do {
            coreDataService.context.delete(folderToDelete)
            try coreDataService.save()
            getFolders()
        } catch {
            print("Error = \(error)")
        }
    }
}

func deleteContent(indexSet : IndexSet) {
    for content in indexSet {
        let contentToDelete = contents[content]
        
        do {
            coreDataService.context.delete(contentToDelete)
            try coreDataService.save()
            getContetns()
        } catch {
            print("Error = \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to do data management by Coredata.
There is 2 models, a folder and contents.
the folder can have many contents, but the content is able to have only one folder.

I tried to delete a folder with onDelete using indexSet and succeeded with the function in my code. but I can't delete a content in a folder with that.

Could you let me know how I can do that?

Comment: If you always wants to delete the content of a folder when the folder is deleted then you can set up the delete rule for the relationship to cascade, google "core data delete rules" for more info. Another option is to use the function `removeFromContents` on `Folder` to remove contents object from a given folder. Note that the function name is `removeFrom<relationship name>` so it might be named something different

Comment: Too late to edit my comment, forget the second part of my previous comment. That will not actually delete the content objects only remove the connection between them and the folder. If you want to delete all content objects then loop over them when deleting the folder using `contents` to get all objects for a folder. Again the name is the name of the relationship.

Comment: func deleteChildren(folder : FolderEntity, indexSet : IndexSet) {
        guard let index = indexSet.first else {return}
        let content = contents[index]
        folder.removeFromContents(content)
        coreDataService.save()
        getContents()
        
    }

Comment: Thank you for your nice lesson, I will find way with your point! Thank you for your help !! Joakim!!!